# 'Reminders' app on Iphone

Tags: tasks, activities, push-notification, task-notifications, activity-settings

Our users are seeing their overdue tasks being pushed to the 'reminders' app on their iphones. As a System Admin, I looked around everywhere on how to 1. enable/ disable this setting 2. customize this feature so that not just the overdue tasks but all tasks are pushed to the app. Any insights are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.